# Use an Openshift edge route to an external VM

Tags: networking, kubernetes, openshift

I have several VM's running and I have an Openshift cluster. All exposed application *in* my cluster have HTTPS through Openshift edge routing. Now I would like to add a url and https to my VM's too (*note that my VM's are NOT running in my Openshift cluster*).

I tried to achieve this by creating a service that points to my VM's IP (say 1.2.3.4):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: harbor-vm-service
  namespace: harbor
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  externalIPs:
    - 1.2.3.4
  selector:
    special: harbor
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And then create an edge route pointing to that service:

`oc create route edge harbor --service=harbor-vm-service`

However it doesn't work; I just get *"Application is not available"*.

Am I making a mistake?
Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?